# How to retrieve a very big cassandra table and delete some unuse data from it?

Tags: cassandra

I hava created a cassandra table with 20 million records. Now I want to delete the expired data  decided by one none primary key column. But it doesn't support the operation on the column. So I try to retrieve the table and get the data line by line to delete the data.Unfortunately,it is too huge to retrieve. Otherwise,I couldn't delete the whole table, how could I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually, how to get the data from the table in bulks (also called *pagination*).

You can do that by selecting different slices from your primary key: For example, if your primary key is some sort of ID, select a range of IDs each time, process the results and do whatever you want to do with them, then get the next range, and so on.

Another way, which depends on the driver you're working with, will be to use fetch_size. You can see a Python example [here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html) and a Java example [here](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.0.10/features/paging/).

Comment: thank u for help . But it really doesn't work for me.My table is some complicated. The primary keys are (a,b,c,d) and a is a varchar ,b is a Long ,c is a varchar,d is a Long.Now I can page it in cqlsh using the query language like this:
       SELECT * FROM usertoken WHERE token(a)>=token('avalue') AND (b,c,d)>=(bvalue,'cvalue',dvalue) LIMIT 1000 ALLOW FILTERING;
The value avalue,bvalue,cvalue,dvalue stand for the last record of previous page.
      But when I use it in spring-data-cassandra,it just return 100 records per page. .What happens?

Comment: Seems like spring does support paging, which can explain it. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/api/) for the spring-data's cassandra paging class.

Comment: MayBe I was misleading by this reference. Now I've got the data by the cassandra-driver directly, but the question is How to convert the row described above to my java class(String a,Long b,String c,Long d).Any suggestion?

Comment: reference[link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Comment: Thank u very much,your answer is helpful for me . Here is my another question about this if u were interested in.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499257/how-to-convert-the-cassandra-row-to-my-java-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499257/how-to-convert-the-cassandra-row-to-my-java-class)