# How to convert the cassandra row to my java class?

Tags: cassandra, typeconverter

```
 Here is [a Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448987/how-to-retrieve-a-very-big-cassandra-table-and-delete-some-unuse-data-from-it#comment52844466_32464409) of my question before.
 After I get  the cassandra data row by row in my program, I'm confused by the convert between cassandra row to java class. In java class the table of cassandra is convert to a ResultSet class,when I iterator it and get the row data,it returns a NPE. In fact,I can see the Object (or the data) while  debuging the program. Here is My Iterator Code:


        ResultSet rs=CassandraTools.getInstance().execute(cql);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = rs.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = iterator.next();
            row.getString()  ---->return NPE
```

The CassandraTools class is:

```
public class CassandraTools {

private static CassandraTools instance;

private CassandraTools() {
}

public static synchronized CassandraTools getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new CassandraTools();
        instance.init();
    }
    return instance;
}

Cluster cluster;
Session session;

public void init() {
    if (cluster == null) {
        cluster = new Cluster.Builder().addContactPoint("10.16.34.96")
                .build();
        if (session == null) {
            session = cluster.connect("uc_passport");
        }
    }
}

public ResultSet execute(String cql) {
    ResultSet rs = session.execute(cql);
    // rs.forEach(n -> {
    // System.out.println(n);
    // });
    return rs;

}
```

}

SO how could I convert the data in the row to A java Class?I have read the convert class in the API of spring data cassandra,but it is complicated to use for me. Who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, If you want to map the rows of Cassandra to a java class, you should try to use an Object-Datastore mapper which does these things for you.

If you try to do this by yourself, you need to handle the java-cassandra datatype mappings, validations etc all by yourself which is very hectic job.

There are few (Kundera, Hibernate OGM, etc) opensource object-datastore mappers available and you can use them. I suggest you to try [`Kundera`](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera) and check this for [`getting started`](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes) with Cassandra.

Comment: Yeah,I have read the wiki of Kundera. Persisitence works well in spring-data-cassandra. But I didn't find the example How to convert the data from db to java class,any help?

Comment: @marsyoung once data is persisted you can just give the query and results are automatically mapped to your java entity. You can refer [this testcase](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/deec1d5f47912748f27b640dd089669f3e71a00d/src/kundera-cassandra/cassandra-core/src/test/java/com/impetus/client/crud/PersonCassandraTest.java#L397) and if you need more help let me know :)

Comment: @ karthik manchala  I have solved the problem using spring-data-cassandra.The code is simple:
`   ResultSet rs=CassandraTools.getInstance().execute(cql);
   CassandraConverter cassandraConverter=new MappingCassandraConverter();
   CassandraConverterRowCallback<UserTokenCassandra> callback= new CassandraConverterRowCallback<UserTokenCassandra>(cassandraConverter, UserTokenCassandra.class);
   
   Iterator<Row> iterator = rs.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = iterator.next();
    utcList.add(callback.doWith(row));
   }`